# fix frame rate of animated gif in Java

Tags: java, animation, animated-gif

I'm making a Java app that displays certain GIF files from a folder. I'm currently using the code

```
  final JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
  imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(fileName));
  contentPane.add(imageLabel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This works flawlessly, except that many (thousands) of my .GIF files have a misconfigured frame rate which makes them display at infinite speed (frameDelay=0), assuming that the browser will fix this automatically. Java does not do this by default. How can I override the frameDelay Java has to use for those animated gifs with frameDelay=0?

Comment: You are converting `ImageIcon` to `Image` and viceversa.

Comment: See [Java Gif on Label Background Squares Showing?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9707490/3453226).

Comment: @Joiner Does that matter? I've edited that now but it makes no difference.

Comment: @Joiner that link seems to deal with transparency and the .gif incorrectly not seeing it as transparent. It does not seem to be related to animation in general, nor to frame delay in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [this](https://community.oracle.com/message/5358959#5358959), and it works well for one gif I tried.

<s>I have no idea what he's exactly doing, but at a glance it looks like</s> if the first frame has a delay of 0 it overwrites the delay for all frames with 10. Then he 'writes' a new GIF file in memory and loads that to image.

[edit] I polished it up a bit and ironed out the bugs.

- No proprietary API
- Doesn't just check the 1st frame to determine if it's bugged,
- Replaces delay only for frames where it's zero.

```
public static Image readImgFromFile(String filename, Component parent) {
    File file = new File(filename);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        return null;
    }

    // Fix for bug when delay is 0
    try {
        // Load anything but GIF the normal way
        if (!filename.substring(filename.length() - 4).equalsIgnoreCase(".gif")) {
            return ImageIO.read(file);
        }

        // Get GIF reader
        ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("gif").next();
        // Give it the stream to decode from
        reader.setInput(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file));

        int numImages = reader.getNumImages(true);

        // Get 'metaFormatName'. Need first frame for that.
        IIOMetadata imageMetaData = reader.getImageMetadata(0);
        String metaFormatName = imageMetaData.getNativeMetadataFormatName();

        // Find out if GIF is bugged
        boolean foundBug = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numImages && !foundBug; i++) {
            // Get metadata
            IIOMetadataNode root = (IIOMetadataNode)reader.getImageMetadata(i).getAsTree(metaFormatName);

            // Find GraphicControlExtension node
            int nNodes = root.getLength();
            for (int j = 0; j < nNodes; j++) {
                Node node = root.item(j);
                if (node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("GraphicControlExtension")) {
                    // Get delay value
                    String delay = ((IIOMetadataNode)node).getAttribute("delayTime");

                    // Check if delay is bugged
                    if (Integer.parseInt(delay) == 0) {
                        foundBug = true;
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Load non-bugged GIF the normal way
        Image image;
        if (!foundBug) {
            image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(filename);
        } else {
            // Prepare streams for image encoding
            ByteArrayOutputStream baoStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try (ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(baoStream)) {
                // Get GIF writer that's compatible with reader
                ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWriter(reader);
                // Give it the stream to encode to
                writer.setOutput(ios);

                writer.prepareWriteSequence(null);

                for (int i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
                    // Get input image
                    BufferedImage frameIn = reader.read(i);

                    // Get input metadata
                    IIOMetadataNode root = (IIOMetadataNode)reader.getImageMetadata(i).getAsTree(metaFormatName);

                    // Find GraphicControlExtension node
                    int nNodes = root.getLength();
                    for (int j = 0; j < nNodes; j++) {
                        Node node = root.item(j);
                        if (node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("GraphicControlExtension")) {
                            // Get delay value
                            String delay = ((IIOMetadataNode)node).getAttribute("delayTime");

                            // Check if delay is bugged
                            if (Integer.parseInt(delay) == 0) {
                                // Overwrite with a valid delay value
                                ((IIOMetadataNode)node).setAttribute("delayTime", "10");
                            }

                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // Create output metadata
                    IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(new ImageTypeSpecifier(frameIn), null);
                    // Copy metadata to output metadata
                    metadata.setFromTree(metadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName(), root);

                    // Create output image
                    IIOImage frameOut = new IIOImage(frameIn, null, metadata);

                    // Encode output image
                    writer.writeToSequence(frameOut, writer.getDefaultWriteParam());
                }

                writer.endWriteSequence();
            }

            // Create image using encoded data
            image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(baoStream.toByteArray());
        }

        // Trigger lazy loading of image
        MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(parent);
        mt.addImage(image, 0);
        try {
            mt.waitForAll();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            image = null;
        }
        return image;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That code was able to fix my current .gif files, thanks! Only one problem: it gives me a warning "GIFImageMetadata is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release". Would there be any way around this? I would of course would like my program to keep working in a future Java release, so if this package is about to disappear then that is a problem.

Comment: Never mind, using the code in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077913/read-delay-between-frames-in-animated-gif I managed to fix that warning, now the code no longer uses the GIFImageMetadata class. It all works now. Thanks a bunch!