# How can i change the speed of GIF file

Tags: java, gif

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL url= new URL("<file path>");
        Icon icon= new ImageIcon(url);
        JLabel label= new JLabel(icon);

        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Test");
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(label);
        mainFrame.setSize(800, 600);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

how can i change the speed of Gif file ?
i tried to find how to change the speed of JFrame frame but i didn't find anything

Comment: Look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801433/fix-frame-rate-of-animated-gif-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. All you can do is create another gif based on your current one. Use [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) for that

Detect current speed:

```
identify -verbose your.gif | grep Delay

Delay: 5x100
...
```

Create a new gif:

```
convert -delay 10x100 your.gif your_slow.gif
```